# Lifetimes of Vector Objects

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust, and I'm struggling with lifetimes and container objects. I created a basic inventory class where the user can add/remove/get Items. I want the Inventory to have ownership of the item, and allow other objects to borrow the Items. I've been struggling with this for a bit, and I've read up on lifetimes. Most of the examples have been pretty simple and different than this. How the heck do I return this Item as a mutable reference?

```
pub trait Item {
    fn get_name(&self) -> String;
    fn get_description(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct Inventory {
    items: Vec<Box<dyn Item>>
}

impl Inventory {
    pub fn new(&self) -> Inventory {
        Inventory {
            items: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn Item>) -> bool {
        true
    }

    pub fn remove(&mut self, item: Box<dyn Item>) -> bool {
        true
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<Box<dyn Item>> {
        return self.items.get(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The `new` method should not take `&self`. It should be: `pub fn new() -> Inventory { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<Box<dyn Item>> { ...
```

This, if it were implemented successfully, would imply that `get` is either *moving* or *copying* the item, not returning a reference to it — there's no `&` so the caller gets to take ownership. The type you want to use to have borrowing is:

```
pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Box<dyn Item>> { ...
```

The `&` is inside the `Option<...>` because the `Option` was created new just for this lookup; it's outside the `Box<...>` because the box already existed and it's what you are wanting to use the method to borrow.

The mutable version of this would be:

```
pub fn get_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<&mut Box<dyn Item>> {
```

Putting it all together into a version of your code that will compile:

```
impl Inventory {
    pub fn new(&self) -> Inventory {
        Inventory {
            items: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, item: Box<dyn Item>) -> bool {
        self.items.push(item);
        true
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.items.get(index)
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<&mut Box<dyn Item>> {
        self.items.get_mut(index)
    }
}
```

Pretty much a wrapper around the `Vec`.

---

I've left out `remove` because it's more complicated to implement, but note that if you write `remove` with the same parameters as `add` then you're passing in *another new object for the `Inventory` to take ownership of,* which probably isn't the best way to express *removing* a mutable object, since you'd need to make a second copy in order to end up with zero copies, and also to define equality between `Item`s.

And you can't use `fn remove(&mut self, item: &Box<dyn Item>)` because that would mean having a mutable reference to `self` at the same time as a reference to *part* of `self`, which is prohibited.

Some alternatives are removal by name, by index, by filtering the items (like [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter)), or even setting a flag in the mutable `Item` that indicates that it should be removed at the next convenient time (e.g. the next time an item is to be added).

Perhaps there's a better idea that should be on this list; I'm pretty new to Rust myself. But most likely, the best option will depend on the requirements — what your `Inventory` actually needs to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this tonight.

Answer (score -1):

What if, instead of returning a new Inventory object, you just set `self.items = Vec::new()` in the struct's `new()` function? Then your calling function can get the object using something like `let inv = Inventory::new()`?

Edit: You can alternatively try to make this an [Associated Function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions) by removing the `&self` parameter, which would make the `new()` function similar to a `static` function in Java.

Disclaimer: I am new to Rust, and this is my understanding of it after reading through the Rust book recently. Please correct me if I'm wrong.